# Check for alt + key js

Tags: javascript

I want to see if the `alt` key and `j`(or any other number or letter) key are being pressed at the same time.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) { 
    if(e.altKey && e.keyPressed == "j") {
        console.log("alt + j pressed")
    }
}
```

This isn't working.

Any help on this?

Comment: I'd recommend logging out e and seeing which properties you need to check for.

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting the event's [`key` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead:

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) { 
    if(e.altKey && e.key == "j") {
        console.log("alt + j pressed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because a [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) does not have a `keyPressed` property. There is a `key` property that indicates which key was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it works

```
var altKeyPressed = false;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {if(e.altKey) {
        altKeyPressed = true;
    }});
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {if(e.key === "j" && altKeyPressed) {
        console.log("alt + j pressed");
        altKeyPressed = false;
    }});
```